# Whats the biggest MicroSD card I can insert in Lumia 535

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-535, micro-sd

I bought Lumia 535 yesterday and realised that I will need more memory. I know that Lumia 535 supports MicroSD cards, but I do not know what size is safe to buy.

I am thinking about buying 32GB MicroSD card. Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest micro SD-Card according to MS is a 128 GB Card. The 32 GB Card shouldn't be a problem at all. The full specs can be viewed [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/phone/lumia535/specifications/)